# Typescript extending a generic type

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics

I have the following generic interface in my typescript code:

```js
interface BaseResponse<T> {
  status_code: string;
  data: T;
}
```

I thought I would be able to use that base interface, without specifying the base's type parameter, in a generic function like this:

```js
class MyService {
    static async post<T extends BaseResponse>(path: string, data: any): Promise<T> {
      // implementation here
    }
}
```

But this gives the following error:
`Generic type 'BaseResponse<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).(2314)`

[image: Error message]

I can fix this error by updating the code like so:

```js
class MyService {
    static async post<T extends BaseResponse<U>, U>(path: string, data: any): Promise<T> {
      // implementation here
    }
}
```

But this requires me to pass two type parameters when I call the function as below. I was hoping I could only pass one and it could infer the second, but that gives me the error `Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.(2558)`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

```js
// What I want to be able to do (Causes error mentioned above):
const response1 = await MyService.post<CustomerResponse>('/customers', postData);

// What I have to do instead (note the two type parameters)
const response2 = await MyService.post<CustomerResponse, CustomerData>('/customers', postData);
```

[image: Actual vs desired behavior]

Comment: In this specific case, I don't see a need for `T extends BaseResponse`. Instead, I'd use `static async post<DataType>(path: string, data: any): Promise<BaseResponse<DataType>>`: https://tsplay.dev/WkMDPN

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - fixed.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder that did the trick.